# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, cgi

Test.py code which takes the values from HTML and printing to file gets an traceback error
Why the error of file descriptor is comming. I am an newbie.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

def get_data():
    '''
    This function writes the HTML data into the file 

    '''

    print "Content- type : text/html\n"

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    f = open("abc.txt","w")

    f.write(form.getvalue('firstname'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('lastname'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('age'))
    f.write(form.getvalue('gender'))
    f.close() 

    #print "Hello ", Fname, Lname, Age, Gender

get_data()
```

Tracebacjk Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
get_data()
File "test.py", line 25, in get_data
f.write(form.getvalue('firstname') + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

My HTML source file

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>INFORMATION</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action = "/cgi-bin/test.py" method = "post">
    FirstName:
    <input type = "text" name = "firstname" /><br>
    LastName:
    <input type = "text" name = "lastname" /><br>
    Age:
    <input type = "text" name = "age" /><br>
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female

    <input type = "submit" name = "submit "value = "SUBMIT">
    <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "RESET">
    </form>
 </body>
```

Added html file.PLease check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code opens the file with write mode (`w`).

You cannot iterate the file opened with write mode.

If you want write the passed POST data to file, just write.  (without `for` loop). Append newline (`\n`) if you want the values are line separated.

```
f = open("abc.txt","w")
f.write(form.getvalue('firstname', '?') + '\n')
f.write(form.getvalue('lastname', '?') + '\n')
f.write(form.getvalue('age', '?') + '\n')
f.write(form.getvalue('gender', '?') + '\n')
f.close()
```

Using `with` is more preferred:

```
with open("abc.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(form.getvalue('firstname', '?') + '\n')
    f.write(form.getvalue('lastname', '?') + '\n')
    f.write(form.getvalue('age', '?') + '\n')
    f.write(form.getvalue('gender', '?') + '\n')
```

---

Did you use `for` to do something like following?

```
with open("abc.txt", "w") as f:
    for param in ['firstname', 'lastname', 'age', 'gender']:
        f.write(form.getvalue(param, '?') + '\n')
```

Comment: When using the first option error:                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    get_data()
  File "test.py", line 25, in get_data
    f.write(form.getvalue('firstname') + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: with is an reserved keyword in python 2.6 so i am unable to use thAT

Comment: @johnjohn, I updated the answer to handle the case when the POST parameter is missing. Check it out.

Comment: @johnjohn, BTW, you can use `with` statement in Python 2.6! Maybe you used it as variable name?

Comment: my file is printing  "?" in the file. I want to print values it takes from html

Comment: @johnjohn, It means you did not submit correctly. Could you show the html page source?

Comment: @johnjohn, Do you access the page using url like `http://..../cgi-bin/test.py` ? You should access the page via a html page (submit).

Comment: i am accessing through 192.168.1.74/~john/cgi-bin/test.py

Comment: @johnjohn, Don't directly access the cgi page. First access the html page, then fill the form, then submit.